$B\subseteq P(\mathbb{N}) : |B| = \aleph \ ?$
The question asked if there exist a set $B\subseteq P(\mathbb{N})$ with cardinality of $\aleph$ such that for all $A_1 ,A_2 \in B$ , if $A_1\neq A_2$ then $A_1 \cap A_2 = \phi$ .
I have looked at the following set $B'= \left \{\  \left \{ 1 \right \},\left \{ 2,3 \right \},\left \{ 4,5,6 \right \},\left \{ 7,8,9,10 \right \}... \right \}$ but it seems with cardenality of $\aleph_0$ because I'm able to tell who is first,second e.t.c (I know that this is not a formal proof).
I also know that if $D\subseteq C$ then $|D| \leq  |C|$ but the condition on the set $B$ prevents me to think further.
Considering these claims, I'm trying to proof there there is no set $B$ but the paper is blank.

You may use \emptyset, \varnothing for the empty set. Some people prefer \O or \o, but these two commands are not supported on this site.

@Asigan great to know!

Such $B$ does not exist. Indeed, assume $B$ exists, and without loss of generality assume the empty set doesn't belong there. (otherwise, just remove it) Then we can define an injection $B\to\mathbb{N}$ by mapping each set $A\in B$ to the minimal element of $A$. This map is indeed injective, because the sets of $B$ are pairwise disjoint. But of course we can't have an injection from a set of cardinality $\aleph$ to $\mathbb{N}$, so it is a contradiction.

Beautiful. Thank you very much for the answer. May I ask how did you came up with the solution? More specific with the injection $B\to \mathbb{N}$ that maps each set $A\in B$ to  to the minimal element of $A$ ?
.

@Daniel The idea is that if we take the union of all the sets of $B$, we must have at least $\aleph$ elements there, because we take the union of $\aleph$ sets, all with different elements. But this is impossible, as the union is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. That's the whole idea. Once you get to this, you just have to find how to turn this into a formal solution, i.e build a map that will contradict the cardinalities. Mapping each set to its minimal element looks like the easiest choice.

What cardinality shoud $B$ have? For a countable $B$ let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime and take $A_n=\{p_n^k\mid k>1\}$ and set $B=\{A_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
Edit:
In general, this is the maximal cardinality that $B$ can have: We can assume that $\emptyset\notin B$ (if it is remove it, doesn't change the cardinality of $B$ (assuming $B$ is infinite)). Then The map $B\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, $A\mapsto \min(A)$ is injective, thus $|B|$ is at most countable.

$\aleph$ means continuum cardinality. Not a common notation, but it exists.

Ah ok, I have not seen that notation before.

I assume by $\mathbb N$ you mean $\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$.
If you mean $\mathbb Z_{>0}$ then this won't affect the general argument.
$\bigcup_{S\in B} S $ is a subset of $\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$ and is therefore at most countable.
$\psi:\bigcup_{S\in B} S\to B-\{\varnothing\} $, $S\ni x\mapsto$ the unique set which $x$ belongs to defines a surjection.
Therefore $B-\{\varnothing\}$ is at most countable, and so is $B$.
